# TypeScript Cannot bind controller scope to view

Tags: angularjs, typescript

Here is my **controller**.

```
 /// <reference path="../../node_modules/definitely-typed-angular/angular.d.ts"/>
 interface IcontrollerScope extends ng.IScope {
 name: string;
  }
  class test {
static $inject: string[] = ["$scope"];
constructor(public $scope: IcontrollerScope) {
    $scope.name = "Sample";
  }
}
```

Here My **App.ts**

```
  var map: ng.IModule = angular.module("map.module", []);
  map.controller('map.controller', test);
```

Here is my HTML :

```
 <body ng-app="map.module">
  <div ng-controller="map.controller">
    {{name}}
    </div>
  </body>
```

When I open the page in browser, it doesn't evaluate the statement **{{name}}** , can some one tell me where is my mistake?

Comment: No errors in your console?
Anyway I'm pretty sure your controller registration is wrong:  map.controller('map.controller', test); should be something like  map.controller('map.controller', test.$inject);

Comment: found it , forgot to include the controller file.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with it except I forgot to include the file in View.